# Updating a table based on a findfirst criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a recordset TBLSOURCETARGETLINK that I want to update on an after update event.

I also need to ensure that no duplicates are present before I add the new record. 
If the record exists, I just want to update the record and add new.

I am struggling with the VBA and the sequencing of how to do it.

Please could someone assist.

VBA currently looks like this:

```
Private Sub IsSource_AfterUpdate()

Dim VbaTableID As Integer
Dim VbaSystemID As Integer
Dim VbaFieldID As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset 
Dim tabledef As String
Dim strcriteria As String


Dim rstSourceTarget As Recordset
Set rstSourceTarget = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="tblsouretargetlink",      Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)


If IsNull(Me!TableID) Then
   Else
        VbaTableID = Me!TableID
End If


If IsNull(Me!SystemID) Then
   Else
        VbaSystemID = Me!SystemID
  End If

If IsNull(Me!FieldID) Then
   Else
        Vbafield = Me!FieldID
End If
strcriteria = "[systemid] = '" & Me.SystemID & "' And [tableid] = " &    Me.TableID And [FieldID] = " & Me.fieldid"

rs.FindFirst strcriteria

   If .NoMatch Then
        With rstSourceTarget
            .AddNew
            ![SystemID] = VbaSystemID
            ![SourceTable] = VbaTableID
            ![SourceField] = VbaFieldID
            .Update
        End With
   Else
        With rstSourceTarget
            .Edit
            ![IsSource] = -1
            .Update
   End If




End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: In the criteria you have wrong quotation, also the last `With` not closed `End With`. What kind of problem do you have with your code? It should work if you fix those two issues.

Comment: What is `rs` recordset? It was not declared nor opened

Comment: VbaField not declared

Comment: at the 
.Nomatch

I get INVALID or UNQUALIFIED reference (no error number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub IsSource_AfterUpdate()

    Dim VbaTableID As Integer
    Dim VbaSystemID As Integer
    Dim VbaFieldID As Integer
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim rstSourceTarget As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    ' don't use CurrentDb for opening recordsets, it's dynamic, you can lose reference to database.
    Set rstSourceTarget = db.OpenRecordset(Name:="tblsouretargetlink", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

    If Not IsNull(Me!TableID) Then
        VbaTableID = Me!TableID
    End If

    If Not IsNull(Me!SystemID) Then
        VbaSystemID = Me!SystemID
    End If

    If Not IsNull(Me!fieldid) Then
        VbaFieldID = Me!fieldid
    End If

    strCriteria = "[systemid] = '" & Me.SystemID & "' And [tableid] = " & Me.TableID & " And [FieldID] = " & Me.fieldid

    With rstSourceTarget
        .FindFirst strCriteria
        If .NoMatch Then
            .AddNew
            ![SystemID] = VbaSystemID
            ![SourceTable] = VbaTableID
            ![SourceField] = VbaFieldID
            .Update
        Else
            .Edit
            ![IsSource] = -1
            .Update
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

There are a lot of errors, so first of all add

```
Option Explicit
```

at the beginning of each module and recompile the project (Debug->Compile)